# Delete pandas dataframe row based on multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df :

```
ABF2
ABG2
ABH2
ABJ3
ABK4
ABM5
ABN6
ABQ7
```

My goal is to have the following data frame :

```
ABH2
ABM5
ABQ7
```

So basically the condition would be multiple :

```
if third char = H, M, Q or Z
```

To get the third char value I do as below :

```
DF.Col_Name[2::2]
```

Fact is that I don't really know how to apply multiple condition to retrieve the wanted DF.
Also, what would be the quickest way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select third character with `str` and test values in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test by membership, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = DF[DF.Col_Name.str[2].isin(['H','M','Q','Z'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.str` accessor

```py
out = df[df['col'].str[2].isin(['H', 'M', 'Q', 'Z'])]
```

```
print(out)

    col
2  ABH2
5  ABM5
7  ABQ7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df.col.str[2].str.contains('H|M|Q|Z')]
```

prints:

```
    col
2  ABH2
5  ABM5
7  ABQ7
```